# Creating a subclass to affect the behavior of another subclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

The library I am using defines an abstract base class `A` with ~10 pure virtual methods. There are no non-pure methods publicly defined and I suspect that `A` has no private data, i.e. the class is merely an interface. The library also defines a few concrete sub-classes of `A`, such as `C`.

I would like to add some functionality to `A` so that all of its sub-classes inherit this functionality. However, `A` is defined in the library and I cannot do this.

Instead, I have defined a new sub-class of `B`. This sub-class is not concrete and all of the pure virtual methods of `A` are left alone. It defines a few new helper methods that call out to the methods defined by `A`. There are also no fields defined by `B`.

In order to use `B` to augment the functionality of instance of `C` I have done the following, which I suspect is not guaranteed behavior.

1. Create an object of type `C` on the heap.
2. Cast the pointer to this object to instead be of type `B*`.
3. Return this pointer, exiting the local scope where the object was created.
4. Call methods defined by `B` using this pointer in a different scope.

Is this safe? The objects are created on the heap, so I don't think any slicing will happen. If the safety depends on which fields `A` and `C` define, what requirements are needed to guarantee this behavior?

If neither `A` nor `C` had their own data other than the vpointer, would this be safe?

What about if only `C` has its own data?

Edit: I should add that I have attempted this and the behavior has at least seemed to be what I want. I have not profiled for memory leaks though.

Comment: No, it's not safe.  Why not create free functions that take an `A` instead of trying to graft extra methods into the interface?

Comment: @MilesBudnek I could do that. I also considered making `B` a container holding a `A*`. I was hoping for a more seamless interface.

Comment: You could make a template holding the added functionality that can derive from any sub-class such as `C`. Then you can `static_cast` from `C*` to the template.

Comment: @Super that sounds promising. Why did you delete your answer? It seems like it would do exactly what I want.

Comment: @JonClaus Just a misclick, i undeleted again.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing looks like code smell to me. I would take the approach for B class of a wrapper class: take an A* pointer in the constructor, forwarding the calls you need to that A*. Then you can pass a C* to that constructor, that will be correctly deleted through a "delete" in B destructor.

Comment: The destructor is virtual and not redefined by `B`. So if the integrity of the vpointer coming from the `C` object is preserved, then the destructor defined by `C` will be called.

Comment: Regarding the container class, is there a way to avoid re-defining in `B` every method that `A` did?

Comment: You are right, I've tested it and C destructor is called, so I will delete it from the answer, but still looks dangerous to me. Regarding the redefining thing, I don't see a good workaround to avoid writing all of them. But in the line of what Miles Budnek commented, you could create free functions, maybe grouped in a namespace/class with static methods, that is used as helper for your C and other A-derived classes. Then you don't have to redefine A interface in B, and everybody can use B-related functionality for C objects

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea following up on my comment. It behaves as intended, might be some hidden dangers but to me it seems reasonable as long as `bar` does not hold any data.

```
#include <iostream>

struct base {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    void show() {
        std::cout << x + y << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void virt() = 0;
};

struct foo : base {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 2;
    void print() {
        std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
        x++;
    }

    void virt() override {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct bar : T {
    void print2() {
        std::cout << T::a * T::b << std::endl;
        T::b++;
        T::x++;
        T::virt();
    }
};

template <typename Base>
bar<Base>* extend_with_bar(Base& base) {
    return static_cast<bar<Base>*>(&base);
}

int main() {
    foo f;

    f.show();
    f.print();

    auto b = extend_with_bar(f);

    b->print2();
    b->print2();
    b->print();
    f.print();
    b->show();
    f.show();

    b->virt();
}
```

Comment: It can work but.... you are in the realm of UB. What if `foo` class has virtual functions and a vtable, like class `A` and `C` have in OP question? does a call to `b->MethodDeclaredPureVirtualInA()` works as expected?

Comment: @GianPaolo I don't see why not. The class inherits from `C` and indirectly from `A`.

Comment: @GianPaolo Updated to include an example of that working.